# Overlap of questions between us and travel.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I've seen quite a [few](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4941/what-are-possible-trekking-routes-in-the-atacama-region-in-mid-april) [questions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/trekkings-in-mongolia-without-guide) asking for travel advise, though about trekking, it feels like these questions would be a better fit for https://travel.stackexchange.com/.

Would it be a good idea to have a migrate option in the close regions, similar to that offered by SO:

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

with a link to travel.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta sites in general do not get quick-migrate paths. If you feel a question is entirely off-topic here, you can flag it for moderator attention with a custom reason saying where you think it would be on-topic.

Comment: But before you do so, make sure the question is pretty much **OFF TOPIC here.** See **[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)**

Comment: I am facing the same issue here.. I spent a lot of time mentally debating where this should go - outdoors or travel? Because surfing is outdoors and i have to travel to a beach that is outdoors for it http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/inexpensive-spots-season-to-stay-1-2-3-months-for-newbie-to-learn-surfing

Answer (score 2):

I think one key guideline (which WedaPashi wrote, more or less, in [a comment to this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/how-safe-is-it-to-travel-from-kathmandu-to-lukla-without-flying-the-distance#comment9446_5366)) is whether the Outdoors community is more likely to know the answer, or the Travel community. It makes sense to leave a question that is likely to get a better answer from our community here. Clear-cut questions can be migrated away, but the ones I've seen so far have been close enough to stay, in my opinion.

Comment: Nicely put! "Clear-cut questions can be migrated away, but the ones I've seen so far have been close enough to stay"